# AdditionalLayoutSupport in Crash Logs

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, autolayout

We're receiving several crash logs with the following error...

-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _internalUpdateConstraintsIfNeededAccumulatingViewsNeedingSecondPassAndViewsNeedingBaselineUpdates:]

We don't ever use updateConstraintsIfNeeded directly, but we do initiate new layout passes in several places by calling, layoutIfNeeded.

Can anyone tell me what this error means, and how we may determine which view(s) are triggering this?